# undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsLatin1String when installing Pillow for local Python

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I used pip to install Pillow. It indicated successful installation of Pillow. But when in Python (v2.7.8), I entered `from PIL import Image`, I got this error:

```
ImportError: /home/local/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/PIL/_imaging.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsLatin1String
```

The problem is that I have a local python v2.7.8 install which is for UCS2 with `maxunicode`: 65535. But the PIL library was built and installed by the system default Python 2.7.6 version, which is UCS4. I suspect pip invoked the default python, v2.7.6.

1. How can I let pip use my local python v2.7.8 to install Pillow instead of using the system default python?
2. How to make Pillow that is built for UCS2 instead of UCS4?
3. Do I need install a different pip for my local python v2.7.8? Current pip is within /usr/bin/ for the system python.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your operating system?  Pillow is not pure python and requires a compilation or installation of binary code.

Comment: The Python best practice to make local Python installations is to user virtualenv and isolated Python environments. Each virtualenv comes with its own `pip` command. Read more about it here https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#virtual-environments and here http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ - In this case pip install should recompile Pillow against your local Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows machine try downloading binaries from here [download python libraries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Here you have an option to provide to which version of python you are trying to install.

Comment: Does it apply to OpenSuse instead of windows? Thanks