# I am using Pillow and getting an error "ImportError :No module named Image" in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, image-processing, tesseract

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?
I have Ubuntu 32-Bit , and Python 32-Bit and Installed Pillow using pip

Here is the code:

```
import Image
import pytesseract
print pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('1.jpg'))
```

Here is the error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/siamak/workspace/test/com/tower/test/ocr.py", line 1, in 
>       import Image
>   ImportError: No module named Image

Comment: you should copy and paste the error into your question as text so that it is searchable for future users of the site.

Comment: can you show the the outputs after apply this:  `import PIL`
`PIL.__version__`

Comment: Uninstall pillow and pip and reinstall those.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
from PIL import Image
```

`Image` is a submodule of `PIL`, so you have to use the `from...import` syntax.

Comment: I tried now it says : from PIL import _imaging as core .I changed it to core and doesn't work

Comment: @SiamakHeshmati Could you provide the full error message?

Comment: here is the full error  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siamak/workspace/test/com/tower/test/ocr2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: /home/siamak/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsLatin1String

Comment: @SiamakHeshmati Are you using Python on Windows? If so, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965487/undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs4-aslatin1string-when-installing-pillow-for-local. Also, if you're using Python 2.6, you'll need to upgrade to 2.7.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu (Linux)

Comment: @SiamakHeshmati What error do you get when you use the exact code from your question, but replace `import Image` with `from PIL import Image`?

Comment: I did and  : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siamak/workspace/test/com/tower/test/ocr2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image 
  File "/home/siamak/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 66, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: /home/siamak/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsLatin1String

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on Linux Mint , and CentOS and it works perfectly .
For some reason it doesn't work on Ubuntu 32 and 64 .
I am assuming it is related to the PIL installation
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem where,

```
from PIL import Image
```

gave this same error as the one in your comment:

> from PIL import _imaging as core
>
> ImportError: /home/jer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so:
>   undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsLatin1String

It seems a locally installed version of Pillow is the culprit. We can [uninstall the local version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524522) with,

```
pip uninstall Pillow
```

This left the system version of Pillow installed, which worked fine.